# How to automate prevention of outbound emails to specific email addresses in G-Suite/Gmail?

Tags: gmail, g-suite

As part of our GDPR work we want to ensure users who no longer want to be contacted by us cannot be accidentally emailed by someone else in the company.

We have a regularly updating list of people who no longer want to be contacted, and wish to automatically update *something* in Gmail to prevent those individuals from being contacted.

We can, as part of the Google Admin tools define routing (https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?hl=en#ServiceSettings/service=email&subtab=filters, routing section) rules that quarantine emails to single addresses or a regex, and I've successfully tested this.

However, the API to enable updating these rules is deprecated and will be removed in October 2018.

What are our options for restricting outbound email to specific addresses without manually updating a list when someone unsubscribes?